# Display data by date, when data comes from multiple models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently working on an app with Django 4.1. I try to display a resume of some data comming from the database. Here is a simplified example of my models:

```py
class Signal(models.Model):
   data1 = models.CharField()
   data2 = models.CharField()
   date = models.DateTimeField()


class Ban(models.Model):
   data3 = models.CharField()
   data4 = models.CharField()
   date = models.DateTimeField()
```

What I'm trying to do is getting filtered data from these 2 models, and make a list ordered by date from all this data to display it. someting like:

- Ban1 (08/03/2023)
- Ban2 (07/03/2023)
- Signal2 (06/03/2023)
- Ban3 (05/03/2023)
- Signal1 (04/03/2023)

Thanks in advance for your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.values()` to get rid of the model layer and produce dicts containing the exact same fields.
You'll then be able to `.union()` to gather your data in a single queryset.
Then a simple `.order_by()` should do the trick.

```py
signals = signals.annotate(data3=Value(""), data4=Value("")).values("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "date")
bans = bans.annotate(data1=Value(""), data2=Value("")).values("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "date")
combined_queryset = qignals | bans
combined_queryset = combined_queryset.order_by("date")
```

If data1 and data3 should be in the same column you can do

```py
signals = signals.annotate(new_data1=F("data1"), new_data2=F("data2")).values("new_data1", "new_data2", "date")
bans = bans.annotate(new_data1=F("data3"), new_data2=F("data4")).values("new_data1", "new_data2", "date")
combined_queryset = qignals | bans
combined_queryset = combined_queryset.order_by("date")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's queryset API to retrieve and combine the data from the Signal and Ban models, and then sort them by date.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Signal, Ban

def resume_view(request):
    signals = Signal.objects.order_by('-date')[:5]
    bans = Ban.objects.order_by('-date')[:5]

data = sorted(list(signals) + list(bans), key=lambda x: x.date, reverse=True)

context = {'data': data}
return render(request, 'resume.html', context)
```

In your html:

```
{% for item in data %}
  <p>{{ item.__class__.__name__ }}{{ forloop.counter }} ({{ item.date|date:"d/m/Y" }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That seems good but I wanted to avoid sorting it in python. I prefer make a big query ;)